# default padding class in bootstrap available

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a **[Bootply](http://bootply.com/)** for my work but i am little bit confused that there is any default padding class in bootstrap. Or am i missing something ? [My HTML work is here](http://www.bootply.com/blaAmFmwcW).

There is no padding between each row class what am i missing? i don't want to write my own css.I am using **bootstrap 3.2** version. I want to know class of equal px padding which can be used in every html element.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and click the check mark if you like the answer

Comment: There are no vertical padding classes in Bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a default padding.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3">
```

Its the `offset` class that does it you can make it `lg` or `sm` or whatever size along with the column size i.e `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`.

You can look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) for examples.

Comment: thanks @Jay. and one thing more .row class has margin-left and right with -15px. but what if i want margin-bottom between each row. ?

Comment: Then you can 1) add that to the css your self in the css file or just 2) `style=''` the div where you want it. 3) write your own `.row` css and just cut and paste most the one from the bootstrap.css and add the margin. Personally I like option 2 (Don't forget to click the check mark next to my post) :)